# How to print bold list number of a paragraph in python?

Tags: python, python-docx

I have this text in an MS Word document (.docx):

```
    1. best animal is :
    a. cat
    **b. dog**
    c. snake
    2. second best animal is:
    a. rhino
    b. tiger
    **c. puma**
```

dog and puma are bold text and the correct answers in a word file with lots of these questions.

Now i'm trying to use python to loop through the text content, identify bold paragraps and output it to json as the correct answers.

my issue is that while i can print the bold identified text as it's style in word apprently is Heading 1 i cannot print the letter assigned to it in list

For e.g. i can print in json text=dog , text=puma but cannot print text=b. dog, text=c. puma

this is the code i am using now:

```
import docx
import jsonpickle

doc_file = docx.Document('C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/test.docx')
json_output = []
for paragraph in doc_file.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading 1') and paragraph.style.font.bold:
        json_output.append({'text': paragraph.text, 'bold': True})
   

json_string = jsonpickle.encode(json_output)

print(json_string)
```

can anyone advise to the solution?

Comment: May just have been a typo as you pasted here but you're missing a ' in your path to the docx file

Comment: Can you add the word file to your question?

Comment: @mrblue6 yes, was a typo, corrected now

Comment: @AliasCartellano here you go we.tl/t-OwxlDxAbE3

Comment: It is probably a numbered list in the word document and `a`. `b.` `c.` are the _"numbers"_ of the numbered list, not part of the text. Hopefully you can get info about the list style, which would give you the format of the _"numbers"_.

Comment: BTW I edited your question so that it does not look like you are parsing plain text.

Comment: @zvone it is a numbered list but can't get the a. b. c. in the results, paragraph extracts only text after them

Comment: Try looking for the list bullets using `paragraph.style.name.startswith("List Bullet")`.

Comment: @AliasCartellano this returns nothing, empty array.

i used another code to print all detected styles, i got :

List Paragraph
Body Text
Heading 1
Normal

. Looping through with list paragraph also gives an empty array